# SQL memory - sys.dm_os_memory_objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, memory, sql-server-2014

So if you run the following, it clearly shows which parts of SQL are using the most memory.

```
SELECT SUM (pages_in_bytes) as 'Bytes Used', type 
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_objects 
GROUP BY type 
ORDER BY 'Bytes Used' DESC; 
GO
```

Does anyone have an article anywhere ( i have searched the net!) for what each 'type' actually is? Specifically MEMOBJ_SOSWORKER

cheers - any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23323/sql-server-and-very-hot-cpu-of-total-wait-time) many years back.

The answer/comments pointed to  great [reference](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) by Paul S. Randal.

SQL Server has many stats that can safely be ignored. If you include all wait timers available it can skew the average.

Also, there is a lot of info about the SOS Worker [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/) if you scroll down to the S's.

Comment: Don't feed the off-topic trolls ;-) (asking for off-site resources is off-topic on SO)